# Unknown Display after kernel update with (old) graphics card NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 950]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display, display-resolution

I have a NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 950]  and have the most recent drives. I did a software update through the GUI and after reboot I got using the boot option "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic", when I boot my screen is not recognized, and I am locked at 1024 x 768 resolution. When I boot with "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-50-generic" my screen works and lets me use the correct aspect ratio and resolution (16:9 up to 3840x2160). I tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` and the `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove; sudo update-grub` loop several times to no avail.

Below I'll put the output of `xrandr --verbose`, and `nvidia-settings` when I boot with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic and the screen isn't working.

`xrandr --verbose`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (0x523) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x522
    Timestamp:  71382
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1024x768 (0x523) 59.769MHz *current
        h: width  1024 start    0 end    0 total 1024 skew    0 clock  58.37KHz
        v: height  768 start    0 end    0 total  768           clock  76.00Hz
```

`nvidia-settings`:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux josephe-desktop 5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 13:09:46 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dkms status`:

```
zsh: command not found: dkms
```

I am using nvidia-515 proprietary which I believe is what was installed with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` a while ago. I am trying to install nvidia-520 now.

**edit** after switching to the proprietary `nvidia-drivers-520` everything works and here is the current output of `dkms status`:

```
dkms status
nvidia, 520.56.06, 5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 520.56.06, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: What is the output of `dkms status`?  There is a good chance that the driver you are using is not DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) ready.  Please add the output to your question.

Comment: Which nvidia driver are you using?  My gtx 970 system lists the nvidia-driver-515 as the (tested) recommended driver when running ubuntu-drivers devices or Software & Updates/Additional Drivers tab. I have run the 520 driver without problem, but not the 515-open or the 520-open.

Comment: Updated my answer with the output of `dkms` status and what my current driver is. Currently trying to install the 520 driver to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Updating the drivers to 520 (which wasn't the recommended driver as ubfan1 mentioned) seems to have fixed the issue on the 5.15.0-52-generic kernel.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and if upvoted, accept it in a few days, giving you some rep points and helping others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appeared to be related to dkms.

I was using `nvidia-515` proprietary which I believe is what was installed with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` a while ago.

After switching to the proprietary `nvidia-drivers-520` through the Software & Updates/Additional Drivers tab, everything works on both kernel versions. Here is the output of `dkms status` after updating:

```
dkms status
nvidia, 520.56.06, 5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 520.56.06, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
```